# What happen if my Skyrim disc broke and it won't load into the game?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My menu screen is still normal but I when I press into continue, the game froze and I don't want to press new game.

Comment: There's not much of an answer we can give here. If the disc is broken/damaged, you'll need to replace it. - As a tip, do check around if there's any retro/modern game stores around you as they usually have a DVD Buffer that can help get games working again.

Comment: I assume console.  PC version is Steam Powered.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, there isn't much to do other than to get a new disc.

To expand a bit on what you're worried about, starting a new game by pressing "New Game" won't affect your saved games at all. Neither will a new disc; saves are stored on the console's hard drive.

Without more information on how "broken" your disc is (going from a few scratches to deep furrows/warping), we can't tell you anything further about potential fixes, other than replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Really, you'll just have to get a new disk.